# Activating a relay when certain voltage received (Water injection system)

Tags: voltage, sensor, relay

I decided to build a simple water/methanol injection system for my car and now I'm thinking about a simple way to activate the water pump only from certain boost level. For the boost reading I'm planning to use map sensor. The map sensor has +12v supply, ground and output pin (5v max). The output voltage varies depending on the boost pressure.

What would be the easiest way to activate a relay which turns on the pump when certain voltage (or more) is received at the output from the map sensor? Ideally with a potentiometer for the boost level adjustment but that would be just a nice to have option.

Comment: A Schmitt-trigger comparator (with a significant  hysteresis and pre-filtering) is the first thing that comes in mind

Comment: An adjustable pressure switch maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparator. Connect the middle pin of your potentiometer to the negative input and the sensor output to the positive input. Connect the potentiometer between 5V and ground.
The comparator should have a schmitt trigger input, to avoid toggeling of the relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZfZJC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will propably have to put a FET at the output of the comparator to drive the current of the relay. And don't forget to put a flyback diode over to relay to avoid destroying your FET.

Comment: Remember that many comparator devices have open-collector outputs, so they will require a pull-up resistor on the output.